# Не много не понимаю как работает тернарный оператор "?" или вообще дело не в нем

Tags: javascript

Немного изучаю js и столкнулся с проблемой.

Насколько я понял, тернарный оператор "?" это более короткая вариация if, то есть если у нас условие верно, то выполняется первое выражение, если нет, то второе.

Первый пример:

```
const number = function fac(n) 
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1) ;
}

console.log(number(3));
```

Как бы в этом примере все понятно, 3 больше двух и выполняется второе выражение: 3 * 3 - 1 = 6

Но во втором примере я не понимаю почему такой результат:

```
 const number = function fac(n) 
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1) ;
}

console.log(number(4)); //24
```

В моем понимании должно получаться 12, но почему 24 не понимаю.

Извините за возможный глупый вопрос, но правда не понятно

Comment: Факториал 4 это 24 (Мы берём 4 и умножаем результат для этой функции при n = 3 и это 6 т.е 4*6=24)

Comment: Дополню ответ выше. Факториал - это произведения множества от 1 до n. Значит факториал 4 будет 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24

Comment: Почему 12, можете расписать свою логику, чтобы понять где именно вы ошиблись в рассуждениях?

Comment: 12 потому что я мыслил методами обычно математики. 3 * 3-1. Не знал что такое в принципе факториал, просто попался такой пример и смог его нормально понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ваша проблема не в понимании тернарного оператора, а рекурсии. Попробую объяснить. При вызове `number(4)` происходит 4 рекурсивных вызова функции `fac` с аргументами от 4 до 1

```
fac(4)
fac(3)
fac(2)
fac(1) // вот тут тернарный оператор и выдаст true ибо 1 < 2
```

Рассмотрим эту цепочку вызовов в обратной последовательности, мы уже знаем что `fac(1) = 1` ибо выполняется первая часть тернарного оператора. теперь рассмотрим `fac(2)` исходя из условия функции

```
fac(2) = 2 * fac(2-1) // ибо 2 не меньше 2
```

но мы уже знаем что

```
fac(2-1) = fac(1) = 1
```

соответственно

```
fac(2) = 2 * 1 = 2
```

общая картина уже будет такой:

```
fac(4)
fac(3)
fac(2) // 2
fac(1) // 1
```

Идем далее

```
fac(3) = 3 * fac(3-1) // fac(3-1) = fac(2) = 2
fac(3) = 3 * 2 = 6
```

общий стек вызовов уже будет следующим

```
fac(4)
fac(3) // 6
fac(2) // 2
fac(1) // 1
```

ну и последний вызов

```
fac(4) = 4 * fac(4-1) // fac(4-1) = fac(3) = 6
fac(4) = 4 * 6 = 24
```

Финальный стек вызовов уже будет таким

```
fac(4) // 24
fac(3) // 6
fac(2) // 2
fac(1) // 1
```